# Why was my question deemed to be opinion based?

Tags: support, closed-questions, opinion-based

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247303/why-use-switch-expression-instead-of-switch-statement) question about why one would choose to use a C# switch expression over a switch statement.

It has been closed as being opinion based, but I don't understand why.

I researched it first but couldn't find an answer in the MS docs or on the site. It has an example and a clear question, and has an answer which is factual and provides some additional useful information. The answer doesn't have a citation but that isn't the fault of the question. If I had found this answer when I had originally searched it would have satisfied my enquiry.

I would happily edit the question but I cannot for the life of my understand how to do so to satisfy the site requirements.

Comment: Maybe you could change "any advantage" to "technical reasons"? As in, does it influence the produced code for better or worse?

Comment: You might have missed the point, the close reason **is** the answer.  It doesn't matter what you pick, select the syntax you prefer.

Comment: It sounds reasonable to me. It's not asking "Which is better?", which is clearly asking for opinions. There must be an objective reason or two why a warning is generated, despite the fact that deciding whether the warning is worth obeying is off-topic here.

Comment: There is no objective reason why one option is one option is "better" than the other. That's particularly true for the example you are showing. The warning you get from Visual Studio is because the style guide that the IDE is using. But it's about style and readability, not about technical merit. Those are conventions, and are governed by opinions and custom.

Comment: @exnihilo No... it's not, because you can just provide a lambda as the expression in the expression style and put breakpoints in the lambda

Comment: I don't think it's convoluted at all, it's relatively straight forward if anything... which kinda pushes more in the direction of opinion based

Comment: So Stack Overflow still uses the "close reasons count as answers" approach to questions...

Comment: Related blog post: *[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)*. *"Apply the six subjective question guidelines and see how it scores. If the score is low, close it. If the score is high, vote it up. ... 1) Great subjective questions inspire answers that explain “why” and “how” 2) Great subjective questions tend to have long, not short, answers. 4) Great subjective questions invite sharing experiences over opinions 5) Great subjective questions insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references"*

Comment: @BoltClock #SOcloseismu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very often, questions like this are, indeed, asking for opinions. Stack Overflow tends to err on the side of caution and (mis)categorize every single question that involves opinions as opinion-based, because sometimes askers can't tell the difference, or, in very rare cases, [askers seem to understand the difference but insist on pushing their own agenda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431595/why-use-specific-vendor-prefixes-instead-of-one-representing-all-browsers), turning what would have been a perfectly fine question answerable with documentation and/or evidence, into an opinion piece.

In this specific case, if you're asking why *Visual Studio 2019* is recommending the change, to which the answer could be any of:

- Visual Studio generally recommends updating legacy code of any kind to new syntax according to the language version declared by the current project, even if for the sake of making it look more modern and succinct, without providing any real advantages. This often happens to projects that always declare to use "the latest version available" and get migrated to a newer version of Visual Studio down the road.
- There's an objective, functional difference between the two notations which isn't immediately made clear by the IDE's real-time suggestion.
- Some other design decision, opinionated or not, by the language designers or anyone else involved.

Then I recommend making this clearer in your question. Perhaps ask for a quote from the documentation (but even that will probably get you a few "don't ask for links to external sites" close votes). Or merely spell out that you're looking for the IDE's rationale for making such a suggestion.

Either way, I find Sean's answer to your question quite satisfactory.

Comment: I think what bothers me about eagerly closing questions is that closing the wrong ones can send the wrong message to askers and readers.

Comment: On the other hand, a little effort on the part of the askers, or editors, would also go a long way. For instance, in this answer BoltClock points out something that could be made clearer in the question. The OP can do that, or users who can see that the question is close to getting closed can do that. There is a shared responsibility here that seems to be pointed primarily at those closing questions (a relatively rare event in the scheme of things) in this answer...

Comment: I really appreciated this constructive answer and the ensuing comments, thank you.